# Why commits by github don't show 'verified' (signed commits)?

Tags: git, github, gnupg, gpg-signature

I got the git commits from my local repo to show 'verified' on github, by setting up the gpg key.

But why my commits by github (while I am on github) don't show up as 'verified'?  It shows nothing, indicating github sees them as unverified commits. Is this expected or maybe I need to configure something on github?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I did.  Otherwise, local commits wouldn't show up as 'verified' on github right?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot sign commits/tags created via GitHub web interface. Only local commits/tags can be signed.

This is because a signing key consists of two parts — public and private. And private keys **MUST NEVER LEAVE** your computer.

The public part can encrypt data, the private decrypt it so only you can read the encrypted data. The private key signs data, the public key verifies so only you can sign with your key but anyone can verify your signatures.

When you upload a GPG key to GitHub you only upload the public key so GitHub can only verify signed commits/tags but cannot sign them.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you phd!

Comment: So, I assume it's a good practice to make commits via local git then, even during a github Pull Request code review process.  Right?  So that way, all my commits are verified.  It is tempting to make code updates on github though when the update is a simple change, since it's easy and quick.  But I will stay from that temptation :)

Comment: @pdn2020 I don't use signed commits — too much trouble entering password every time (and yes, I use `gpg-agent` but with a short timeout — 15 minutes). I only use signed tags so I can accept a merge via web UI and I don't worry about signing the merge.

Comment: @pdn2020 This is a completely different question and should be asked as a separate question, not as a comment here.

Answer (score 4):

At some point in Fall 2020, possibly between 1-20 October, GitHub changed the way they handle GPG key commit verifications rebases where ONLY the git `COMMITTER_DATE` is changed.

So here's my very normal usecase flow:

1. I find a very small problem in a commit for a feature that hasn't been released yet.
2. I commit it then rebase away the transient fix commit.
3. Because more than 1 day has elapsed, github will report my activity of the original file as occuring today.
4. I fix that by doing `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date <HASH>`, which resets the GitHub file-modded date to the commit's datetime, not today/now.

Before 20 October, I had never had a problem in over 8 years doing these steps.

Now, all of a sudden, GitHub is showing all commits caught up in this rebase as being unverified:

[image]

You can see for yourself over at https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/commits/fucked_up_gpg_verifications

The error reported? "No user is associated with the committer email.", which is patently ridiculous, as all the commits share the same email address and it's the main one on the account.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. If you are committing something on GitHub.com web (e.g. editing the README.md file by clicking the pencil icon and then commit by clicking the [commit button on GitHub web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOIYf.png)), the expected behavior is that the commit is signed by Github.com (using [GPG key ID: 4AEE18F83AFDEB23](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173493/who-owns-the-gpg-key-4aee18f83afdeb23-and-how-did-it-sign-a-commit-in-my-github) in my case)

[image: Screenshot of GitHub signature]

Comment: How did you get github.com to sign your commits? My commits are all partially verified (or unverified if vigilant mode is enabled).

Comment: @Android I think this is the expected behavior of vigilant mode: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/displaying-verification-statuses-for-all-of-your-commits#about-vigilant-mode